# Fixed length Validation using Javax api

Tags: java, validation, jaxb, bean-validation

request response can be validated using javax annotation. However, need some help to have fixed length validation, as @Size(min=3, max=3). It is having message that 'size must be between 3 and 3'. This is required to be changed.

Comment: What is the problem?  Do you want to change the message?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the default **@Size** message just declare parameter `message` into:

```
@Size(min = 3, max = 3, message = "Your constraint message")
private int anyNumber;
```